# How to search / replace an attribute name in all instances of a *specific* class in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

We have inherited a Python code base that has various classes with an 'id' attribute (example: Product.id; Service.id; User.id; ...). The code base has various instances of those classes (example: the Service class has instances named: service1, service2, company.service, etc.). We want to search / replace all occurrences of the 'id' attribute in the whole code base by a new attribute (for example: serv_id). But we also want to make sure that it does not replace the 'id' attributes of other class instances in the process. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Here is an article of how to use search in VS Code : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_find-and-replace
Also, for your purpose I would search for something.id instead of just searching for id. However, to do so you will need to know beforehand which class you want to change.

Comment: That will not be possible, unless you have a very smart IDE that allows you to do that. Maybe PyCharm will do it but I'm not sure, that would mean checking the type of the declared variable, seeing if it's an instance of that class and replacing it. But what if the type of the variable is determined by an `if` statement? Or maybe it's returned by a function. The IDE should be able to also detect that, and that basically means running the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a rename refactoring for those individual classes' `id` attribute (best option would be using the Microsoft Python Language Server).

Comment: Thanks Brett....I will have to check out how the Microsoft PLS works......I had no idea it existed.